# Unity with dual displays: resize causes jump to other display

Tags: 16.04, unity, laptop

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity on my laptop with an external display. When an application (e.g. Terminal) is on the external display and I attempt to resize it by clicking on the left side of the window, the window jumps to the built-in display in a minimized (and garbled/corrupted) state. However, I can correctly resize the window on the built-in display, or on the external display when clicking on the right side. Any suggestions on how I might fix this behavior?

I'm seeing this with Unity version 7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1.